# keep or remove a ddr4 2gb ram module in my laptop, how much difference in battery life

Tags: laptop, linux-mint, battery

i have an 8 GB DDR4 and a 2 GB DDR4 ram modules in my laptop, i can easily run my everyday things with 8 GB, battery life is tricky on my Acer aspire E5-553 with Linux mint on it, i get between 3-4 hrs max, if i remove the 2 GB module, how much gain in battery life , should i expect? I've read that DDR4 runs on 1.2 volts but i don't know what it means to power consumption in terms of my 45wh, 16v, 4 cell lithium ion battery.

Comment: You could just take the Ram out and test it but I'm taking a guess that the battery use difference will be negligible if at all noticeable.

Comment: There will be no difference or such a small difference you wouldn't be able to measure it (few seconds to perhaps a few minutes) but even that difference would be depending on the old of the CPU during that testing phase not because of how much memory you have installed or how much memory was "used"

Comment: it seems that i should rather keep it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, a your 2 gig DIMM will use in the order of 1.5 watts.

The figure I've calculated seems unreasonably high, but I get a figure in the order of magnitude of 10% extra battery life.   I get this as follows:

1.5 watts x 3 hours runtime = 4.5 watt hours, or about 10% of the rated capacity of your battery.

Comment: That isn't how you calculate Wh typically. A memory module requires 1.5 volts not 1.5 watts.  If a single 2 GB module requires 1.5 Wh then I am deeply concerned for my phone and every mobile device in existence because they will never have more memory then they already have.  You would have to know the resistance of the module to calculate wattage.

Comment: still waiting for a reasonable answer

Comment: @ramhound No, a DDR4 memory module apparently and surprisingly requires in the order of 1.5 watts from what I discovered while researching - otherwise I'd be great full if you could find the error in my logic (I know the difference between watts, amps, volts, resistance)- You raise a good point but cellphones do not use DDR, and also a 4 gig dimm uses similar power to an 8 gig one -(and desktop similar to SODIMM). If my answer IS wrong I'd be very interested in why - but it's not because I confused watts

Comment: DDR4 requires 1.5 Watts?  Samsung's [documentation](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/file/media/DDR4_Brochure-0.pdf) says 1.2 volts.

Comment: @ramhound - I could not find anything specific to 2GB memory, but according to Toms Hardware for 1.2 volt DDR4 type memory, yes - that order off magnitude  - http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/intel-core-i7-5960x-haswell-e-cpu,3918-13.html

Comment: 1.2 volts but how did you determine the wattage?

Comment: @ramhound The article I linked to is all about voltages TomsHardware actually measured, so I'm going on the wattages in the article. Wattage of memory is a surprisingly elusive figure !

Comment: i removed the 2 GB module

Comment: i did a trial and error type test to verify these things. what i found out is the battery life improved by 20 minutes after removing the 2 gb module,  i further installed 4.11 kernel and removed tlp, installed laptop-mode-tools, removed cpu freq utilities. and i got an hour increased in battery backup.

Comment: Very interesting - well done. Have you run powertop?

Comment: no but i've used it before , after extensive testing with all these power related software , i can conclude that with the new kernel 4.11 , you are better off without them. even laptop-mode-tools was also unnecessarily causing cpu wakeups